# When using autofac, how do I use a WebAPI controller type name as a parameter to a depencency's Register?

Tags: asp.net-web-api, log4net, autofac

I'm using autofac and trying to register WebApi controllers.  Each controller takes a unique `Logging.ILog` as a constructor parameter (this is my ILog adapts to the log4net ILog).  When loggers are resolved I would like them to be named according to the controller they are being resolved for.

Something like this:

```
builder.Register(c => log4net.LogManager.GetLogger("NEED CONTROLLER NAME HERE"));   
builder.Register(c => new Logging.Adapters.Log4NetAdapter(c.Resolve<log4net.ILog>()));
builder.RegisterType<Logging.Adapters.Log4NetAdapter>().As<Logging.ILog>();         
builder.RegisterApiControllers(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
```

Any idea how I can have each WebApi controller receive an individual logger name according to the controller type name?

The following seems to work but doesn't seem ideal.

```
builder.Register(c => log4net.LogManager.GetLogger(c.ComponentRegistry.Registrations.Last().Activator.LimitType.Name));
builder.Register(c => new Logging.Adapters.Log4NetAdapter(c.Resolve<log4net.ILog>()));
builder.RegisterType<Logging.Adapters.Log4NetAdapter>().As<Logging.ILog>();       
builder.RegisterApiControllers(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
```

I'm new to autofac so bear with me.
If you notice above I have an additional layer or my own ILog and Log4NetAdapter/Wrapper so that there are a few layer of registrations between the controller and the actual log4net.

I need something like:

```
APIController <- Logging.ILog <- Logging.Adapters.Log4NetAdapter <- log4net.ILog <- log4net.LogManager.GetLogger(APIController-Name)
```

Comment: My solution to find the root type (controller) didn't seem to work.  Apparently c.ComponentRegistry.Registrations isn't a stack of the current types being activated it just looks like a list of all registrations.  So when I added other controllers I wasn't resolving the correct controller name.

Answer (score 0):

The Log4net integration docs are available on the [Autofac wiki](http://code.google.com/p/autofac/wiki/Log4NetIntegration).

From the docs:

```
public class LogInjectionModule : Module
{
    protected override void AttachToComponentRegistration(IComponentRegistry registry, IComponentRegistration registration)
    {
        registration.Preparing += OnComponentPreparing;
    }

    static void OnComponentPreparing(object sender, PreparingEventArgs e)
    {
        var t = e.Component.Activator.LimitType;
        e.Parameters = e.Parameters.Union(new[]
        {
            new ResolvedParameter((p, i) => p.ParameterType == typeof(ILog), (p, i) => LogManager.GetLogger(t))
        });
    }
}
```

Modify the above just slightly to pull the name off the `LimitType`, as in your excerpt, and you won't have to pass the parameters any more.

Comment: I modified my question a bit because I actually have a couple layer of types in between my controllers and log4net. I have an additional adapter and ILog. In your solution above it yields a logger named according to my adapter instead of the controller

Answer (score 0):

I use NLog with a wrapper, but it's certainly convertable to log4net. Here's my code:

```
public class LoggingModule : Module
{
    protected override void Load(ContainerBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.Register((c, p) => GetLogger(p.TypedAs<Type>()));
    }

    protected override void AttachToComponentRegistration(
        IComponentRegistry registry, IComponentRegistration registration)
    {
        registration.Preparing +=
            (sender, args) =>
            {
                var forType = args.Component.Activator.LimitType;

                var logParameter = new ResolvedParameter(
                    (p, c) => p.ParameterType == typeof (ILog),
                    (p, c) => c.ResolveLog(forType));

                args.Parameters = args.Parameters.Union(new[] {logParameter});
            };
    }

    public static ILog GetLogger(Type type)
    {
        return new NLogLogger(type);
    }
}

public static class ResolveLogExtension
{
    public static ILog ResolveLog<TService>(this IComponentContext context)
    {
        return context.ResolveLog(typeof (TService));
    }

    public static ILog ResolveLog(this IComponentContext context, Type type)
    {
        return context.Resolve<ILog>(TypedParameter.From(type));
    }
}

public interface ILog
{
    void Debug(string format, params object[] args);
    void Info(string format, params object[] args);
    void Warn(string format, params object[] args);

    void Error(string format, params object[] args);
    void Error(Exception ex);
    void Error(Exception ex, string format, params object[] args);

    void Fatal(Exception ex, string format, params object[] args);
}

public class NLogLogger : ILog
{
    private readonly Logger _log;

    public NLogLogger(Type type)
    {
        _log = LogManager.GetLogger(type.FullName);
    }

    public void Debug(string format, params object[] args)
    {
        _log.Debug(format, args);
    }

    public void Info(string format, params object[] args)
    {
        _log.Info(format, args);
    }

    public void Warn(string format, params object[] args)
    {
        _log.Warn(format, args);
    }

    public void Error(string format, params object[] args)
    {
        _log.Error(format, args);
    }

    public void Error(Exception ex)
    {
        _log.ErrorException("", ex);
    }

    public void Error(Exception ex, string format, params object[] args)
    {
        _log.ErrorException(string.Format(format, args), ex);
    }

    public void Fatal(Exception ex, string format, params object[] args)
    {
        _log.FatalException(string.Format(format, args), ex);
    }
}
```

Comment: This seems like it name the logger according to the type that depends on the logger.  I have modified my question because I have several type layers in between my controller and log4net.  What I really need is the name of the root type being resolved (and not my adapter in between).