# how to get Resolver class name in autofac?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, autofac, nlog

I am registered Nlog in my Container builder like below:

```
builder.Register( x=> LogManager.GetLogger("LoggerName")).As<NLog.ILogger>();
```

And my Controller constructor like below:

```
       public AccountController(NLog.ILogger logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
    }
```

How can i get resolver class name (in this case "AccountController" ) and use it as GetLogger parameter?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Passing in the type of the declaring class for NLog using Autofac](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6623431/passing-in-the-type-of-the-declaring-class-for-nlog-using-autofac)

Comment: Also heavy overlap/duplication with these questions: http://stackoverflow.com/q/29125250/8116 , http://stackoverflow.com/q/24811956/8116 , http://stackoverflow.com/q/12589898/8116

Answer (score 0):

I found a nuget package, and other implementation of autofac module on github for this Purpose

[Autofac.Extras.NLog](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Autofac.Extras.NLog/)

[Log4Net and NLog modules for Autofac Implementation](https://gist.github.com/pawelpabich/3066496)

Both solves my problem.